# how to make a copy of string into a dynamically allocated character array of the appropriate size?

Tags: c

```
char input[1000];
```

I want to copy input into a dynamically allocated character array, how do I approach this problem.

So far I have used strncpy, but get lots of errors.

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: char *str; str = (char *) malloc(sizeof(input)); strncpy(str, input, 1000);

Comment: What errors you get? Post your code.

Comment: i get implicit declaration of function malloc

Comment: Did you include <stdlib.h> ?

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.:-)

Comment: Lots of errors... that is ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>    
    int main() {
        int i;
        char input[1000] = "Sample string";
        char *in = malloc(1000 * sizeof(char)); // use dynamic number instead of 1000
        strcpy(in, input);
        for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) { // intentionally printing the first 5 character
            printf("%c", in[i]);
        }
    }
```

The output is:

> Sampl

**Edit:** In **C++** the cast is required for `malloc`, so I write:

```
(char *)malloc(1000 * sizeof(char))
```

But in **C**, [never cast the result of malloc().](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: never cast the result of malloc().

Comment: @PeterMiehle, `malloc` returns a void pointer `(void *)`, which indicates that it is a pointer to a region of unknown data type. The use of casting is required in C++ due to the strong type system, whereas this is not the case in C.

Comment: .. and sizeof char is always 1.

Comment: @rakeb.void then again, there's almost no reason to use `malloc` in C++.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is just use **strcpy()** offer by C string.h after dynamically allocating memory to your array, as shown:

```
char *input = malloc(1000*sizeof(char));
```

and if the string you are trying to copy to variable input exceeds the allocated memory size (strlen > 999: don't forget! String has a null terminator '\0' that takes up the additional 1 char space), just realloc as shown:

```
input = realloc(input, 1000*2*sizeof(char));
/* check if realloc works */
if (!input) {
    printf("Unexpected null pointer when realloc.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: Please take a quick look to this example of how to use realloc properly:http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/. Do not assign the result to the old variable directly. If realloc failes your old memory is also lost!

Comment: However, what's the likelihood of your program not being able to realloc a new memory? Even if it's not possible to expand the memory in the existing address, you can move to the new address and allocate the new memory as necessary. I don't think insufficient memory space here is a huge concern.

Comment: It's not about insufficient memory. `realloc` could fail of any other circumstances you can imagine. So its a good practice in the 'c-world' to ALWAYS check results of `malloc`, `realloc` and other `*alloc's` if they returned NULL. Because if so something bad happend and you might want to stop.

Comment: A very good point! Thanks for pointing that out. You reckon creating a function to check if realloc works will do? :)

Comment: Yeap thats the most preferable way of doing it.